# py2exe failed to load specified module

Tags: python, python-2.7, py2exe

I compiled a simple python module using py2exe. It works fine for me when I run the executable through the cmd window, but when I give it to someone without Python installed, they get the following error message:

`LoadLibrary(pythondll) failedThe specified module could not be found. C:\PYTHON27.DLL`

How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Py2exe doesn't actually create one single executable.  You have to include the dlls and other files in the folder.